# Is this the correct way of using React.Suspense?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several questions about React.Suspense.

Here is some example code for reference:

```
// components/ComponentA/index.js
import React from "react";

const style = {
  display: "grid",
  placeItems: "center"
};
export default function ComponentA() {
  return <div style={style}>I am componentA</div>;
}
```

```
// components/ComponentB/index.js
import React from "react";

const style = {
  display: "grid",
  placeItems: "center"
};
export default function ComponentB() {
  return <div style={style}>I am componentB</div>;
}
```

```
// App.js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ComponentA = React.lazy(() => import("./components/ComponentA"));
const ComponentB = React.lazy(() => import("./components/ComponentB"));

export default function App() {
  const [state, toggleState] = React.useReducer((state) => !state, false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggleState}>click to show</button>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {state ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />}
      </React.Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When running this code, I've noticed several things right away.

The first thing I noticed is that when the app loads for the first time, there is a split moment where you can see `loading...` before `I am componentB` is rendered.

The second thing I noticed is that if you click the button, you can, again, for a split moment see `loading...` before `I am componentA` is rendered on the screen.

I assume this is the expected result with dynamic imports.

The final thing that I noticed is that continuing to toggle the button, I never see `loading...` again. I assume that this is because the components have already been imported and used by the client. Which is, I also assume, expected behavior.

My three questions here are,

- am I using React's dynamic imports correctly (or should I use `import` elsewhere) and,
- when should `React.Suspense` and dynamic imports be used

If the components are relatively simple, do I need to even consider lazy loading components?

Sandbox for reference

[image: dazzling-glade-dd6we?]

Answer (score 1):

**For the First question -**
Yes, you are using the `lazy()` function to import components ***Correctly***.

**For the second question -**
From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#suspense),

> Suspense lets components “wait” for something before rendering.

It is used to improve your site's performance with regards to its [**First Contentful Paint**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First_contentful_paint) and **Loading times** on slow or bad networks, as well as for `asynchronous` tasks like data fetching where your component depends on the data returned so you show a `Loading..` message to the user as a `Fallback`.

For example, a component which I have written and used-

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Error404 from "./Error404";
import LoadingSpinner from "./LoadingSpinner";
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import("./Dashboard"));
const Employees = lazy(() => import("./EmployeesPage"));

class Container extends Component {
  //handles paths '/' and '/employees' along with any unknown paths
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        <div id="background">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
                <Dashboard />
              </Suspense>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/employees">
              <Suspense fallback={<LoadingSpinner />}>
                <Employees />
              </Suspense>
            </Route>
            <Route component={Error404} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

- Here, I am *[lazy loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)* my two components `Dashboard` and `Employees` which in themselves contain many components and are relatively complex.
- Lazy loading them prevents the connection to be clogged while loading the site for the first time.
- These components are now loaded *only* when the user navigates to the specified `URL` by some [NavLinks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).
  Since it's safe to assume that the user will spend some time in the `Dashboard` before going to the `Employees` page(at least in my app), this approach works fine.

**For the third question -**

- If you have components that you are sure will be needed **when the site loads**, it's better to not lazy load them to keep the *User Experience* good.
- Small components (by their bundle size) don't need lazy loading, only when you think that many components are gonna be used only rarely, then you can lazy load them in one bundle.

**Lastly -**

- You can open up the Network tab on the `developer tools` of a browser and see the bundles loading in as the user requests for them (React handles that in `lazy()`). *The Bundles are labelled like this- [Network Tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKGFQ.png)*

*Hope you find the answer useful and any recommendations for the post are appreciated✌*